# Solve the following Cauchy Euler equation:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following Cauchy-Euler equation:

$$x^2y''-xy'+y = \ln(x)$$

In class we have solved only homogenous equations, thus I'm not particulary sure how to do this. I tried setting $y=x^\lambda$, but did not seem to work. The logrithm on the right messes up my stuff. I also differentiated with respect to $x$ to remove it and got to the equation:

$$x^3y''' + x^2y'' = 1$$

Which again I can't solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prove that $y=x$ and $y=x\ln(x)$ are solutions of the equation
$x^2y''-xy'+y=0$
for your second equation are $C,x,x\ln(x)$ are solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for a particular solution, try the form $y = a + b \ln(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=e^t$ and then transform the equation to
$$\ddot y-2\dot y+y=t$$ and then solve it